# Assign smarty variable during template time

Tags: php, templates, smarty, assign

In a smarty template I call a user defined function, as a modifier like that:

```
{"myArray"|assignArray}
```

my user defined function in php looks as:

```
function smarty_modifier_assignArray($str)
{
  global $smarty;
  if ($str=="myArray") 
  {
    // it is not constant in real, but comes from a mysql query
    $all = array( array("foo","joe")), array("green", "blue"));
    $smarty-&gt;assign($str,$all);
  }
  return null;
}
```

My purpose is that loading "myArray" from mysql is expensive, and if my template do not need that
array, I don't want to load it. My template follows as:

```
{"myArray"|assignArray}
{foreach from=$myArray item=r}
  {$r[0]}
{/foreach}
```

The problem is, that in the foreach I can't see $myArray (or it is empty). I read in the smarty forum  (v3.x, http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=77671 ) that for speed optimalization the variables are copied to the template space, so after starting a template, one can not assign new variables onto that. Sadly it seems true. I suppose using template {assign ...} I still could do that, but I was not able to generate dynamical multi-level arrays into that {assign ...} :(

What should I do? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign smarty multilevel array while rendering,
use {assign} tag for it.

Syntax,

```
{assign var=foo value=[1,[9,8],3]}   // can be nested
```